# Passing Powershell variable into a SQL INSERT

Tags: sql-server, powershell, variables, sql-insert

I'm quite new when it comes to Powershell and I'm not sure if my method is the best.
How can I pass Powershell variables into SQL using Invoke SQL or the .Net method? All I'm trying to do is to Insert data from the Get-AzureADGroup Display Name and Object Id into a SQL table.

```
$Groups = Get-AzureADGroup -All $true
foreach($Group in $Groups){

$DN = $Group.DisplayName
$ID = $Group.ObjectId

$insertquery="
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table]([DsiplayName],[ObjectId])
VALUES(''$DN'',''$ID'')
"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "Server" -Database "Database" -Query $insertquery
}
```

However, it comes up with the error 'Incorrect syntax near 'GroupDisplayName'. I've tried using " and ' interchangeably in the query with no luck. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try enclosing the variables in a single quote in the query instead of doubling the quotes.

Comment: is the `DsiplayName` normal ? Can you share the full error message please ?

Comment: @PowerCat The school uses class names as Azure group `DisplayName` for example class: CHEM_4TF_43HH - Chemistry class taught by John Smith the error will show the message 'Incorrect syntax near 'CHEM_4TF_43HH'' for each Class.

Comment: @DanGuzman That didn't work unfortunately as the SQL query starts to recognise the value in single quotes and thinks the Insert is the variable named $DN and $ID not the values in the variables.

Comment: I mean, there is a typo. It's DISPLAY, not DSIPLAY